# find command: get files from a start date, with multiple extensions

Tags: shell, terminal, raspbian

When I run this command

```
find /home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/ -type f \( -name "*.mkv" -o -name ".mp4" \) -newermt "2015-12-11"
```

I was expecting to get a list with four files and their respective paths, but instead I only get a single file and path (mkv extension). If I swap the mkv and mp4 extension in the command, then I only get 3 files and paths (the ones with mp4 extension).

What should I do to get both extensions AND filter by an initial date??

Thanks!

Comment: Damn it! How embarassed I am ... That's what happens when you stay long hours in front of the computer. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a wildcard in your `-name '.mp4'` clause.  You probably meant `-name '*.mp4'`